# Unzip apparently split .gz, .sit or .tar archive

Tags: archive, unzip, php-ziparchive, gunzip

We have an old dictionary software that seems to store the data in an SQLite database (an SQLite executable is shipped with the SW). We want to extract this database to create a machine learning database. 
In the installed folder (on Windows), we found a folder named DB that seems to contain the database. It has the following files in it:

```
4096.gz
4096.sit
4096.tar
4097.gz
4097.sit
4097.tar
....
4129.gz
4129.sit
4129.tar
```

I cannot unpack any of them (on my Macbook), I tried the following commands (in all cases for the first and the last file):

- tar -xvf 4129.tar --> tar: Unrecognized archive format.
- gunzip 4129.gz --> gunzip: 4129.gz: not in gzip format.
- used Stuffit (on MacOS) --> The StuffIt Engine was unable to determine the file format.
- Unarchiver and archive utility did not work either.

So my question:
- Does anybody know/has seen somewhere the storage "format", which seems to come in three archive formats in parallel?
- What can I do to further investigate the formats? Or maybe they are encrypted?
- Does anybody have an idea how I could get the data?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried on the windows computer to use winrar or winzip? those applications should be able to open the .gz and .tar .

If this fails, those files are not those format. Maybe they have the extensions, but not really that content. The content could be arbitrary to the application and could use those extensions for "obfuscation".

As a way to verify, if you have a HEX editor check for the signature:

- gz should start with 1F 8B
- tar should start with 75 73 74 61 72 (ustar)
- sqlite should start with 53 51 4c 69 74 65 (SQLite)

Look this wikipedia how to figure out the content of the file by the signatures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

If your are sure that the application use SQLite, look for SQLite signatures.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I tried your suggestion. I could not find a known signature. However, the files seem numbered back to front:

Comment: Sorry, I am still learning the rules here, tried to edit my comment for too long. 

Many thanks for your answer! I tried your suggestion. I could not find a known signature. 

The .gz files are numbered in the first and fourth byte, back to front: DE F8 01 D4--> DF F8 01 D5  --> E0 F8 01 D6
.tar start with FE D0 FC 9X (X is variable)
.sit start with 00 00

So it does not seem to be a standard file format unfortunately...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find any files with those signatures, it could be a proprietary wrapping format. It could be done maybe for: 1- obfuscation or 2- optimization. However the continuous numbers just remind me as disk FAT (or BAM) table, that the first bytes indicate where it should continue next after reading the content of the file.